# Custom-built model class v Rails generated model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and am very keen to learn and understand it inside out. While I was doing a small example I created my own custom-built model class for which I wanted to have a form. I also wanted to apply all the basic validations on all attributes as well when user input the values through the form. But I could not find much help from Rails out-of-the-box features like it provides for ActiveRecords.

The reason why I would like not to have an ActiveRecord and rather a simple custom-built model is that I don't want to persist it at all. In fact my object doesn't have anything to do with database.

What is the best practice to build custom models classes, add validations to their attributes and associate them with appropriate views?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that exactly.  You want a model class that will never persist.  Sounds like you just want to create your own class and add validators, and you can always associate any object with a view, it need not be an ActiveRecord.  Maybe you should give a concrete example so we can better understand your problem, because it's hard for me to imagine a situation where you would want an ActiveRecord-like object but you never actually associate it with your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/

Comment: Is it also possible that I create my model using "rails generate model..." which creates all them CRUD stuff including views for create, update and delete, AND then I override CRUD methods to do something else instead for example printing them all out or whatever. I hope you understand what I am trying to say..